# Convert ticks to minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm looking for a way to convert a BigInt into a time value using SQL, if possible.  In our database, we store TimeSpan.Ticks into a column and I need to know how much time each value represents.  For instance, 3000000000 ticks is equal to 5 minutes.  I only need total minutes for each IssueID.  Here's the SQL I've written to get the results:

```
SELECT i.IssueID, ia.TimeSpent 
FROM IssueActivities ia
INNER JOIN Issues i ON ia.IssueID = i.IssueID
INNER JOIN IssueActivityTypes iat ON ia.IssueActivityTypeID =   iat.IssueActivityTypeID
INNER JOIN AllPOCs apoc ON i.POCID = apoc.AllPOCID
INNER JOIN Users u ON ia.CreatedByUserID = u.UserID
WHERE i.issueid IN (41602, 41908)
AND ia.ActivityDate BETWEEN '03/05/2018 23:59:59' AND '03/06/2019 00:00:01'
ORDER BY ia.IssueID
```

Here's a sample of the results

[image]

I tried to cast the TimeSpent field to a DateTime `CAST((ia.TimeSpent - 599266080000000000) / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60 AS DateTime)` but I get this error message `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.`

Any ideas on how I can get the minute value of the TimeSpent field and either total it on IssueID or just show the minutes in another column (I can then export to excel and calculate it from there).

Comment: Use floating point for the big math, then time_from_parts to compute the time

Comment: Do you round up, or down, the minute value, or show it as a fractional component?

Comment: @MartinParkin - We normally display seconds as well but for this purpose, rounding down will suffice.

Comment: if 3000000000 ticks is equal to 5 minutes then 600000000 = 1min.  divide the timespent/600000000 to get the minute value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert to minutes (rounded down):

```
SELECT i.IssueID, 
  floor(ia.TimeSpent / 600000000.0 ) as minutes
FROM IssueActivities ia
INNER JOIN Issues i ON ia.IssueID = i.IssueID
INNER JOIN IssueActivityTypes iat ON ia.IssueActivityTypeID =   iat.IssueActivityTypeID
INNER JOIN AllPOCs apoc ON i.POCID = apoc.AllPOCID
INNER JOIN Users u ON ia.CreatedByUserID = u.UserID
WHERE i.issueid IN (41602, 41908)
AND ia.ActivityDate BETWEEN '03/05/2018 23:59:59' AND '03/06/2019 00:00:01'
ORDER BY ia.IssueID
```

The `FLOOR()` functions strips the decimal digits of a floating point value.

Answer (score 1):

I do not necessarily understand why you are asking for the result as a `DateTime` if you just need a conversion to the number of minutes, but have a look at the following:

```
SELECT  3000000000 / 600000000.0,
        300000000 / 600000000.0,
        DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 3000000000 / 10000.0, 0),
        DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 300000000 / 10000.0, 0)
```

The first two operations convert the ticks to the number of minutes (with fractional components preserved).

The second two effectively create a `DateTime` with the number of milliseconds added corresponding to the number of ticks.

You need to consider whether you need the fractional output or not, and whether you need it as a `DateTime` or not.

Comment: I don't need it as a `DateTime`, I only need to show minutes and they can be rounded down.